# How to get form data of orchard cms in another form

Tags: visual-studio, orchardcms

In orchard cms I created a page, a custom form and a widget ,I want to get the data of posted page in another page .Can i refer a html page as a iframe in orchard cms's page which is in the root directory of orchard cms ?

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make much sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you looking to have information that somebody fills in one form automatically populate when they go to another form? If so you might want to look into local storage as one option. If you want data that somebody submits in a form to show up on another page, look into custom forms.